# what is difference between ship to customer and bill to customer in oracle apps

Tags: oracle-apps

what is difference between ship to customer and bill to customer in oracle apps.Can you all provide sql query to get these two field for particular sales order

Answer (score 1):

Columns ship_ and invoice_to_org_id link to hz_cust_site_uses_all.
You can use our Blitz Report: https://www.enginatics.com/reports/ont-order-headers-and-lines/ which shows the link:

```
x.ship_to_org_id=hcsua1.site_use_id(+) and
x.invoice_to_org_id=hcsua2.site_use_id(+) and
```

Note that the ship_to and invoice_to address from header level serve as a default for newly entered lines, and the addresses can be different on line level.